# Cancel Autosuggestion in Visual Studio Code with a custom button

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm staring to use Visual Studio Code.  I want to cancel the auto complete with a custom button.  Right now it involves pressing the escape button which is very awkward.  I really want to use the right arrow button to cancel the suggestion.  Is there a way to set this?

I had to turn off the `acceptSuggestionOnEnter` because it really messed up my workflow.

The best I have been able to do is,

```
editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter: "off"
editor.tabCompletion: "on"
```

But again, I'd like to use the enter button to accept, I just want to be able to cancel the suggestion with the right arrow key instead of the escape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `hideSuggestWidget` keybinding to the right arrow.